# dictionary extracting from natural sentence, and ordering

Tags: python

i have input text (natural sentence), and i have a dictionary of my own.
got to extract the dictionary words from input text.
**so i coded like this :**

```
a = "Today's recipe is 'fried rice'. At first, fry basic mix of frozen chopped \
vegetables with with cooking oil. The vege may includes carrot and pea and onion. \
Then add up chopped bacons. Next, scramble two eggs. Then shake it all together. \
At last, you can use mayonnaise or soy sauce or salt on your favor."

b = ["bacon", "carrot", "egg", "oil", "onion", "pea", "rice", "salt", "soy"]

print([o for o in b if o in a])
```

**and so, output would be like this :**

```
['bacon', 'carrot', 'egg', 'oil', 'onion', 'pea', 'rice', 'salt', 'soy']
```

so, this list is sorted by dictionary list order.
but, I need the list sorted by arrival order in sentence.
**the result must be like :**

```
"rice", "oil", "carrot", "pea", "onion", "bacons", "eggs", "soy", "salt".
```

maybe there is simple snap tuning of the code to fix it.
please help me.

Comment: It may be worth getting the indices of the individual words in the text. By gathering each index, you can create a conditional function/functions to sort the words. This could be done through indexing the entire text or the words themselves. You could also push the target words to a list or array and sort them after you've gathered the data.

Comment: Sorting your list comprehension by order words occur in text a: `sorted([o for o in b if o in a], key = lambda k: a.index(k))`

Answer (score 0):

You can get an index of each dictionary item in text and sort

```
c = [(a.index(o), o) for o in b if o in a]

print(sorted(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with `a` and the `b`.
In long format

```
a = "..."
b = {...}
for word in a
  if word in b
     print (word)
```

Comment: When iterating through a string `for word in a`, you iterate character by character. So `word` would not actually be a word, but a character. To do it like this, you'd need to split the string `a` into words first and then iterate over the word-list.